# Pull in site footer dynamically in MVC Asp.net

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a footer design laid out that is hard coded.  The issue I have is that I need the code to be pulled in dynamically based on an appsetting or an html.helper.  My application has themes, and in the appsettings you can specify which clients theme to use.  This tells it to pull certain css and what not, but the app itself is hardcoded with no dynamic code changes.

The footer is coded like a normal footer, I thought about using a partialview but I don't know how to load a partial view based on which appsetting is set.

I tried doing an html.helper

```
public static MvcHtmlString ThemeFooter(this HtmlHelper helper, string fileName, string alt = "", int width = 0, int height = 0, string cssClass = "", string id = "")
    {
        var clientFooter = string.Format("{0}/Content/{1}/Footer", HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppVirtualPath, AppSettings.ClientName);
        if (HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppVirtualPath == "/")
        {
            clientFooter = string.Format("/Content/{0}/Footer", AppSettings.ClientName);
        }

        var fullFileName = string.Format("{0}/{1}", clientFooter, fileName);



        return MvcHtmlString.Create(fullFileName));
    }
```

but that didn't work as it wouldn't render the partialview based on whos theme it was in.

Comment: Which part of the code you have doesn't work?  How do you define "Doesn't work?"  is it returning a footer correctly, but it is just not different based on the user's settings?

Comment: To be honest it just doesn't seem to be rendering anything.

Comment: It renders it as a string and not the actual partialview "/Content/xxxxx/Footer/footer.cshtml"